# How to increase the precision of the elapsed time indicator in vscode jupyter notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, time, jupyter-notebook

The vscode jupyter notebook shows the elapsed time it took for a cell to run in the lower left corner. However, it seems to shows as 0.0s when the computation is faster than 100 ms.

How to increase the precision of the elapsed time indicator to show less than 0.0s ?

I tried to evaluate a cell that lasted less than 0.0s and the indicator only showed 0.0s.

Comment: historically related?: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1454

Comment: @user Hi, yes that link seems to be about the feature request that led to the elapsed time indicator. I did not see anything there that could help other than maybe the mention of a notebook api.

Comment: if there isn't an Extension which provides this functionality, you probably need to create your own or modify the VSC or Jupiter source code and Build it yourself .